# Access fields in a named union

Tags: c++, c++11, unions

I want to have a named union in the following struct so that I can `memcpy` it without knowing what field is "active".

```
struct Literal {
  enum class Type : size_t {
    INT = 1,
    LONG,
    FLOAT,
    DOUBLE
  } type;

  union {
    int li;
    long ll;
    float lf;
    double ld;
  } v;

  constexpr Literal(int li): type{Type::INT}, v.li{li} {}
  constexpr Literal(long ll): type{Type::LONG}, v.ll{ll} {}
  constexpr Literal(float lf): type{Type::FLOAT}, v.lf{lf} {}
  constexpr Literal(double ld): type{Type::DOUBLE}, v.ld{ld} {}
};
```

How can I initialize the fields in the constructors? Neither `v.li{li}` nor `li{li}` are working.

I also tried `v{li}` but it work only for the first constructor because it cast the 3 others to int.

---

EDIT: From @StoryTeller answer and comment:

```
struct Literal {
  enum class Type : size_t {
    INT = 1,
    LONG,
    FLOAT,
    DOUBLE
  } type;
  union {
    #define UNION_FIELDS int li; long ll; float lf; double ld;
    union { UNION_FIELDS } value;
    union { UNION_FIELDS };
  };
};
```

Comment: If I remove `constexpr` the struct is no longer a POD right?

Comment: `constexpr` and POD-ness are not in direct relation to each other. Quite the opposite, only literal types can have `constexpr` c'tors, but having a constexpr c'tor is not a requirement.

Comment: I though struct cannot be POD if they have constructor(s)

Comment: Well, that's true. But a `constexpr` c'tor is still a c'tor. Your goals seem conflicting.

Comment: I may have misunderstood how `constexpr` works but since it imply `inline` I thought the constructors would "disappear"

Comment: No, they don't disappear. They just allow you to create instances at compile-time (sometimes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only initialize direct members of `Literal` in its c'tors member initializer list. Aggregate initialization of the union member won't work due to narrowing conversions. So your options are to:

1. Name the union member type, and add appropriate c'tors to it.
2. Recurse in order to force the union fields into being treated as fields of the `Literal` class. Have a union of unions, and rely on the common initial sequence guarantee:

   ```
   union {
     union {
         int li;
         long ll;
         float lf;
         double ld;
     } v;
     union {
         int li;
         long ll;
         float lf;
         double ld;
     };
   };

   constexpr Literal(int li): type{Type::INT}, li{li} {}
   constexpr Literal(long ll): type{Type::LONG}, ll{ll} {}
   constexpr Literal(float lf): type{Type::FLOAT}, lf{lf} {}
   constexpr Literal(double ld): type{Type::DOUBLE}, ld{ld} {}
   ```

   The above allows you to refer to each field by name, on account of the anonnymous union member, as well as lumping them together using the named `v` member. But I'll be the first to admit, it's ugly.

Comment: Ugly but clever :)

Comment: @DBLouis - I'll probably be shunned for this... but you can use the preprocessor to avoid repetition....